# Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection

Tags: pdo, php, sql-injection, sql, mysql

Уже давно меня мучает вопрос: **Как защитить свой сайт от SQL-Injection.** В былые времена я использовал `mysql_real string_escape` для экранирования кавычек. Но прошло некое время, и я узнал про `PDO`, говорится, мол, эта тема неплохо поможет в защите сайта. Скажем, я не великий хакер и никак это не могу проверить, я знаю, что при `mysql_real string_escape` все кавычки и прочая ерунда экранировались - и вуаля, вы уже в домике.

Сейчас я работаю над своим проектом и решил проверить сайт на защиту проникновения. В результате, что я делал:

Я просто брал и вводил данные с кавычками, например, **Infor`mat'ion.** Как я уже говорил, я не великий хакер, но точно знаю, что вся эта дрянь должна экранироваться, но она так и заносилась в базу данных, что натолкнуло меня на мысль, что никакой защиты у меня, по сути, и нету. А данные я заносил вот таким вот образом:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO chat (time, login, private, text) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
$db->prepare($sql)->execute(array($time, $login, $private, $text));`
```

Этот метод я вычитал на хабре в ["Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/), подключение такое же, как и указано в статье.

Как можно защититься от этих инъекций?

Comment: @IamS Я немного дополнил ответ. Возможно, Вам или сообществу будет интересно узнать, какие ещё меры можно/нужно предпринять, чтобы "спать спокойно".

Comment: Вывод вы сделали неверный, отсуда и все проблемы. `но точно знаю, что вся эта дрянь должна экранироваться, но она так и заносилась в базу данных`. Эта дрянь экраниловалась, что бы она записалась в базу в том виде, что есть и не повлияла на выполнение запроса, в том числе, не изменила его поведение, тем самым протисояв SQL инъекциям. Т.е. экранирование сделало свое дело, в базу попало именно то, что ввел пользователь. Вот если бы вашь запрос обломался, было бы очень плохо, ибо позволило вставив в текст кусок SQL, выполнить его.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

При использовании [подготовленных выражений (prepared statement)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) параметры внешнего происхождения отправляются на сервер отдельно от самого запроса либо автоматически экранируются клиентской библиотекой.

Создаём таблицу `drop_table`. Далее

```
$name = "Evil'); DROP TABLE drop_table;--";

$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) values('{$name}');";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

Таблица `drop_table` успешно удалена. :)

Теперь тот же запрос, но только через prepared statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test` (`name`) values(?);";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute([$name]);
```

В таблицу `test` добавилась запись `Evil'); DROP TABLE drop_table;--`

#### UPDATE

---

Таким образом, мы обезопасили себя от [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), но не защитили от [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).

В последнем случае требуется:

- **валидация**. К примеру, если необходимо оповестить пользователя о недопустимости введёных им данных либо для логирования;
- **санитизация**. Приведение данных к соответствующему типу `(int)$age`. В PHP существует [набор фильтров](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php), созданных именно для таких случаев;
- **использования облегченного языка разметки**. [Markdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) - именно им Вы и пользуетесь на хэшкоде, либо можно задействовать старичка [bbCode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BbCode). В идеале заставить не только рядового пользователя, но и администрацию сайта пользоваться им. В целях оптимизации, (чтобы каждый раз не парсить), можно воспользоваться key-value storage (memcached, redis,...) для хранения html версии.

> Если по каким-то причинам требуется хранить в базе html от источника, который не вызывает доверие, то можно воспользоваться [HTML Purifier](https://github.com/ezyang/htmlpurifier).

Немного рекламы: :)

- для валидации: [Rock Validate](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-validate)
- для санитизации: [Rock Sanitize](https://github.com/romeOz/rock-sanitize)

Answer (score 6):

Все правильно: в таблицу и должна добавляться строка «Infor`mat'ion». Экранирование должно происходить именно в момент запроса, а не храниться в таком виде. И PDO прекрасно с этим справляется. <s>И `mysql_real_escape_string` (и `mysqli_real_escape_string`) — тоже. И даже `str_replace` — это тоже способ защититься.</s> ***(См. UPD)*** То новое, что нам дает PDO, так это слежение за типами передаваемых данных и разграничение действия и данных. Популярная ошибка, которая приводила к плачевным результатам заключалась в том, что некоторые забывали проверять нестроковые типы:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ".$_GET['post_id'];
```

Разница налицо:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ".intval($_GET['post_id']);
```

Или просто *всегда* обрабатывай входные данные, следи за кавычками, за возможными представлениями чисел, за представлениями `bool`-данных... Или просто положись на готовую обертку, к примеру, PDO. :)

**UPD: WARNING!**

`mysqli_real_escape_string` (вероятно), `mysql_real_escape_string`, а тем более `str_replace` — небезопасны (\xbf\x27 и другие проблемы), используйте MySQL только в режиме *настоящих* подготовленных запросов! [PDO нужно правильно использовать](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/234125/) (спасибо @romeo за ссылку).

Comment: P.S.
Кстати, мне вот интересно: PDO ведет себя так, будто он передает MySQL запрос и ассоциированные параметры отдельно. Это так, или он все таки на своей стороне формирует обычный запрос?

Comment: @Bars, умеет оба кейса, насколько знаю.

Comment: @Bars PDO по дефолту эмулирует это поведения для всех движков, в том числе и для тех, которые в этом не нуждаются (к примеру, mysql из таких). [Почитать](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/234125/).

Comment: @romeo, большое спасибо за чтиво, я как раз недавно сталкивался с ошибкой, которая была следствием эмуляции, и никак не мог понять в чем дело:

 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users LIMIT :limit");
 $stmt->bindValue('limit', 10);
 $stmt->execute();

 /*
 ...check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' 
 */

Я догадался указывать тип (делал ORM, так что, моя система это позволяла):

 $stmt->bindValue('limit', 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Но теперь я знаю первопричину проблемы, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

PDO, и его prepare.

```
$temp = $mysql->prepare('DELETE FROM `unigies` WHERE `idUser` = :idUser Limit 1;');
$temp->bindParam(':idUser', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$temp->execute();
```