# Фильтрация введённых данных перед записью в базу

Tags: php

Как можно сделать, простенькую функцию для фильтрации данных, перед записю в базу данных ?

```
$text = trim($_POST['text']);   // Удалить пробелы в начале и конце строки
$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  $text); // Удалить лишние пробелы в середине строки
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

Comment: Может неправильно сформулировал вопрос (я имел в виду как создать функцию, через которую можно, фильтровать текст, который добавляется в базу данных).

Comment: Использовать PDO и плейсхолдеры.

Comment: Может быть имеется в виду валидация, а не фильтрация?

Comment: @pavlov: Почитайте [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/393456/10551), который я давал ранее. Особенно после "Update".

Comment: @romeo Вы профессионалы, а я только любител, мне нужно сделать простенькую функцию для торого чтобы из текста удалить пробелы, html код ... Не могу понять как создать функцию.

Comment: @pavlov: В вашем примере, достаточно `mysql_real_escape_string`. `trim` и `preg_replace` скорее в нагрузку, это не про безопасность, а про нормализацию данных. `mysql_real_escape_string` и иные mysql-процедурны [не рекомендуется использовать](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-escape-string.php). В PHP 7 всё это дело выпилют. [Используйте PDO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/) с плейсхолдерами.