# Защищен ли запрос от SQL инъекций?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Подскажите функции для защиты) вот сам запрос) 
Все параметры в метод передаются из строки запроса.

```
$catSlug = Slug категории

$page = страница пагинации


public static function catProductList($catSlug, $page = 1)
    {

        if ($catSlug) {

        $page = intval($page);

        $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;

        $db = Db::getConnection();
        $catProd = array();

        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE status='1' AND category_sl='$catSlug' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT." OFFSET ".$offset);


        $i = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch()){
            $catProd[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $catProd[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $catProd[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $catProd[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
            $catProd[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
            $catProd[$i]['slug'] = $row['slug'];
            $i++;
        }
        return $catProd;

        }


    }
```

Comment: А где сама фильтрация запроса? Защита от SQL идёт специальным списком функции. Так для MySQL в PHP есть `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, query)` для PDO есть подновлённые запросы, и так далее.

Comment: Ну я об этом и говорю. Не знаю какую функцию применить

Comment: Нет (и 11 символов)

Comment: подскажите функции для защиты

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#prepared

Comment: смотри сколько вопросов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8  открой, почитай наиболее популярные

Comment: и еще [Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393450/191482) и много еще [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=инъекции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Comment: Ну какой вы драйвер используете? Mysqli? Используй mysqli_real_escape_string, если PDO то подготовленные запросы.

Answer (score -2):

В принципе, если строго следить за типами данных, которые приходят в таблицу, можно обойтись без специальных функций экранирования данных. Но, в случае невнимательности, могут возникнуть проблемы. И так как вы и так используете PDO, то работайте с подготовленными выражениями. Что может на первый взгляд показаться и сложным, и легко допустить ошибку, но есть решение, это передача данных в подготовленные выражения массивом, они с ним отлично работают.

Comment: Забавный комментарий. Допустим, я *строго проследил*, что $catSlug у меня типа sting. Значит, можно обойтись?

Comment: Строго следить это к примеру, использовать в качестве ключей в базе только цифры и ничего кроме цифр, ни каких строк вообще и не пропускать ни чего кроме цифр определенной длины. А записывать, в базу только текст, ни каких специальных символов и прочего.

Comment: WUT?! Какие такие "ключи в базе данных"?

Comment: Хватит в дурочку играть)) Вы прекрасно понимаете о чем я. И судя по карме должны понимать)) И дураку ясно. Что если нельзя будет передать в запросе, допустим строку, только число, то кроме как получить данные из нужной ячейки ничего не получится. Что такое SQL инъекции и как они работают, вам объяснять думаю не надо, судя по карме. И да я в своих проектах использую подготовленные выражения. Жаль тут нет возможности по дискутировать, так бы я с вами по общался еще на эту тему.

Comment: @Денис вы отвечаете на дубликат популярного вопроса, на который уже дан развернутый ответ. причем отвечаете кратко, без деталей, и уже после того, как автору вопроса указали на факт дубликата - отсюда такая жесткая реакция со стороны некоторых участников :)