# Убрать ошибку, возникающую при неудачной авторизации через HTML форму в MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Есть код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <?php
        $title = "Сайт гильдии";
        require_once "blocks/head.php"
        ?> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php require_once "blocks/header.php" ?>
        <div id="wrapper"> 
            <div id="leftCol">
                <div>


                    <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['nik']) && isset($_POST['class']) 
                            && isset($_POST['type']) && isset($_POST['part']) 
                            && isset($_POST['hole']) && isset($_POST['zatocka'])
                                    && isset($_POST['summ']) && isset($_POST['log'])
                             && isset($_POST['pass'])) {


                        $nik = $_POST['nik'];
                        $class = $_POST['class'];
                        $type = $_POST['type'];
                        $part = $_POST['part'];
                        $hole = $_POST['hole'];
                        $zatocka = $_POST['zatocka'];
                        $summ = $_POST['summ'];
                        $log = $_POST['log'];
                        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

                        $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "$log", "$pass", "rf", "3306");
                        mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            exit ("Вы ввели неправильный Логин и/или пароль");
                            echo "провал" . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }
                        $query1 = "INSERT INTO `sklad` (nik, class, type, part, hole, zatocka, summ) VALUES ('$nik', '$class', '$type', '$part', '$hole', '$zatocka', '$summ');";
                        $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);

                        if ($result1 = 'true') {
                            echo '<h3 style="color:#ff0000">Информация занесена в базу данных</h3>' . "<br>";
                        } else {
                            echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
                        }

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM  sklad;"; //выбрать все записи из таблицы nickname
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
...
```

и обычная HTML форма, которую заполняет пользователь на PHP странице и которая передает в этот код/файл глобальные переменные, включая последними: логин и пароль к базе данных MySQL. Если пользователь заранее вводит верные данные, включая логин/пароль, то никаких проблем нет, все добавляется в БД. Но если пользователь указал неверные логин и/или пароль, то сверху выводятся ошибки, вида:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' to database 'rf' in C:\wamp64\www\site\bd2.php on line
>   34
>
> Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\site\bd2.php on line 35

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как убрать эти ошибки и оставить только фразу, которая сразу идет после этих ошибок.

> Вы ввели неправильный Логин и/или пароль

P.S. Я новичок. Многие технологии мне не знакомы.

Comment: В чем прикол доверять пользователю логин/пароль mysql? У вас доступ к mysql разрешен только с локалхоста? :)

Comment: Пока я только таким образом могу реализовать просмотр информации. Не хватает навыков для чего то более глобального. Доступ у конкретного пользователя будет только на чтение. (Примитивная система авторизации)

Comment: О_О плохая идея

Comment: жесть конечно. Такого еще даже не видел ни разу

Answer (score 0):

В общем на твой вопрос могу ответить так.

Дополню что нужно пользоваться функцие парса конфигурационного файла.

[parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php)

В котором нужно прописать настройки коннекта и много чего еще. И создать константы.

Затем нужно еще приконектиться к базе единожды используя паттерн [Singeltone](https://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/325492/#imagehttpshabrastorageorgfiles46db1404e46db1404ea144dbf8b16073d5397698dpng-odinochka). Ну и далее "кнопки" Классы для добавления, чего либо, либо для доставания чего либо из базы.

> Warning: mysqli_set_charset() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\site\bd2.php on line 35

Здесь нужно приводить к строке все данные. Которые должны быть как строка в базе, и чистить их.

**Ну хоть так))**

---

**$name=htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])));
$name=(string)$name;**

---

Второе, мне кажется что тут нужно вот так

```
if (!$con) {
                        die ("Вы ввели неправильный Логин и/или пароль".PHP_EOL."провал" . mysqli_connect_error().PHP_EOL);

                    }else{
                    $query1 = "INSERT INTO `sklad` (nik, class, type, part, hole, zatocka, summ) VALUES ('$nik', '$class', '$type', '$part', '$hole', '$zatocka', '$summ');";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: Спасибо, но появилась другая ошибка: Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\wamp64\www\site\bd2.php on line 34

Comment: просто переменную нужно объявить выше вот так $con='';

Comment: А на самом деле если ты только изучаешь я бы тебе порекомендовал сделать чуть подругому коннект к базе как ? Пиши я тебе пришлю как на голом PHP это сделать.

Comment: теперь с правильным логином и паролем к базе подключается. Ладно, спасибо за помощь. Сам еще поковыряю. Видимо в запросе ветвления где то неточность.

Comment: На самом деле конектиться к базе нужно в отдельном файле. Я имею ввиду, что нужно познакомиться с такой функцией как parse_ini_file http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php, в котором нужно прописать настройки коннекта. А логирование пользователя осуществлять с помощью формы. Предложить польхователю войти или зарегестрироваться. И уже тогдадать ему кнопку вносить что то в базу. или удалять или еще чего.

Comment: `$name=htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))); $name=(string)$name;` **БРЕД** времен PHP4!

Comment: @Visman а что бы ты порекомендовал?

Comment: dpi, я понимаю все, что ты говоришь. И я с этим полностью согласен. И я считаю это более разумным, но более долгим решением для меня в данной ситуации.

Comment: @dpi, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393450/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511895/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083

Comment: Хорошо, я обязательно ознакомлюсь с этим, как подтяну свой синтаксис, чтобы это понять. Спасибо.

Comment: @АлександрБолдырев это не синтаксис, а дополнительный раздел информации из книги/справочника.