# Что не так с запросом?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Хочу сделать возможным редактирование конкретной статьи, а не всех имеющихся, не могу построить правильный запрос:

В этом случае возникает ошибка:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<?php   

    include 'bd.php';

    $zagolovok = $_POST['zagolovok'];
    $smallopisanie = $_POST['smallopisanie'];
    $opisanie = $_POST['opisanie']; 

    $editid  = $_GET[edit];

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE news WHERE id = '$editid' SET zagolovok = replace('$zagolovok','zagolovok','$zagolovok')");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if ($result) {
        echo "<center><p style='color: #404040; font-size: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Gerbera''>Статья отредактирована</p><br><a style='color: #1d97e1; font-size: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Gerbera'' href='adminpanel'>Назад в админ-панель</div></a></center>";
    }

?>
```

В этом случае редактируются все статьи:

```
<?php   

    include 'bd.php';

    $zagolovok = $_POST['zagolovok'];
    $smallopisanie = $_POST['smallopisanie'];
    $opisanie = $_POST['opisanie']; 

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE news SET zagolovok = replace('$zagolovok','zagolovok','$zagolovok' WHERE id = '$editid')");
    if (!$result) {
        die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    if ($result) {
        echo "<center><p style='color: #404040; font-size: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Gerbera''>Статья отредактирована</p><br><a style='color: #1d97e1; font-size: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Gerbera'' href='adminpanel'>Назад в админ-панель</div></a></center>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Синтаксис UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html А еще используете функции **mysql_...** которые уже устарели и удалены в php7  и данные принятые от пользователя вставляете прямо в запрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/511896/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/393456/186083

Comment: @Visman, тогда в таком случае каким образом заменить содержимое 
конкретной статьи?

Comment: точно также, но изучить PDO

Comment: @Jean-Claude, пример покажите?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: и http://phpfaq.ru/pdo

Answer (score 0):

исправьте последовательность

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE `news`  SET `zagolovok` = REPLACE(`zagolovok`,'zagolovok','$zagolovok') WHERE `id` = '$editid' ");
```

но я бы порекомендовал немного другой код по проще

```
$result = mysql_query('
  UPDATE `news`
  SET `zagolovok` = \''.$zagolovok.'\' 
  WHERE `id` = \''.$editid.'\' 
  ');
```

В вашем коде я не увидел правильно ли берется переменная `$editid`
Также хотел обратить ваше внимание на неправильное применение синтаксиса функции `REPLACE`

" $editid пуст" - пока он пуст ни один запрос у вас не получится.

у вас в коде должно быть что то вроде

```
$editid = $_POST['editid '];
```

Рекомендую прислушаться к пользователю @Mike - и отказаться от использования mysql_query в пользу php PDO

Comment: В таком случае он вообще не хочет заменять содержимое

Comment: @user273992 Начните со строки `$editid  = $_GET[edit];` она вообще то должна как минимум предупреждения давать, если конечно у вас нет константы с именем edit. А потом срочно переходите на PDO и не подставляйте значения переменных в текст запроса никогда, иначе вас взломают через неделю после того как этот код заработает в интернете

Comment: @Mike, $editid пуст, он передается на страницу редактирования информации, а вот сохранения уже нет.

https://imgur.com/a/IfxCf