# Как вывести данные из БД

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня в БД есть поле(varchar) и в нем хранятся слова через запятую (Слово, слово2, слово3) и у меня вопрос: Как правильно с помощью цикла вывести эти значения в выпадающий список после каждой запятой новый < option > ? Использую MySQLi.

```
$tagList = $mysqli->query("SELECT `tagList` FROM `groupData` WHERE `groupID` = '$groupID'");
```

Comment: Sql injection...

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста как защитится от них ?

Comment: Не подставлять переменные в запросы.

Comment: А как без этого обойтись ? У меня в переменной хранится значение взятое из api урла ВК.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/393456/178988

Comment: Премного благодарен !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это значение разбить explode и потом циклом перебирать массив

Answer (score 1):

цикл не нужен

```
$pieces = explode(",", $tagList);
```

Comment: Для вывода нужен. Ну или join, но там краёв не хватает