# Запись данных массива в базу данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных, динамические-массивы

**Доброго времени суток.**
Имеется массив (только числовой) $_POST['ch'] и массив $_POST['osel'] (так же числовой)

Имеются таблицы базы данных `prices`

```
id
model
name
priceor
pricecopy
```

и `orders`

```
id
denominations
additional
quality
warr
prices
atotal
ophumber
oname
status
date
uid
```

Инпуты передаются как:

```
$_POST['oadd']
$_POST['onphone']
$_POST['oname']
```

В массиве **$_POST['ch']** хранятся id с таблицы `prices`.
В массиве **$_POST['osel']** хранятся value выбранных select.

Как записать данные в таблицу `orders`, где:

- `id` = авто,
- `denominations` = данные через запятую массива $_POST['ch'],
- `additional` = данные с инпута $_POST['oadd'],
- `quality` = данные через запятую с массива $_POST['osel'],
- `warr` = данные через запятую с массива $_POST['osel'],
- `prices` = если значение select (данные select'ов передаются в массиве $_POST['osel']) было передано как 0 - то считывать данные с таблицы `prices` столбика `priceor`, а если 1 - то считывать данные с таблицы `prices` столбика `pricecopy`,
- `atotal` = сумма тех чисел, которые будут записываться через запятую в ячейку `prices`,
- `ophumber` = данные с инпута $_POST['onphone'],
- `oname` = данные с инпута $_POST['oname'],
- `status` = 0,
- `date` = дата записи (время и число),
- `uid` = 0.

?

PS: Пробовал так, но не получается записать в колонки `prices` и `atotal` :

```
    session_start();
                    $sch = $_SESSION['ch'];
                    if(!empty($sch)) {
                        $denominations = implode(', ', $sch);
                        $quality = $warr = implode(', ', $_POST['osel']);
                        echo $denominations;
                        echo $quality;
                        $priceids = implode(', ', $_POST['osel']);
                        if ($_POST['osel'] == 0) {
                            $query = "SELECT `priceor` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN ({$priceids})";
                        } else {
                            $query = "SELECT `pricecopy` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN ({$priceids})";
                        }
                        $result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, $query);
                        while ($prices_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $prices = implode(', ', $prices_query);
                        }
                        $atotal = 0;
                        foreach($prices_query as $p) {
                            $atotal += $p;
                        }
                        $query1 = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`denominations`, `additional`, `quality`, `warr`, `prices`, `atotal`, `ophumber`, `oname`, `status`, `date`, `uid`) VALUES ('{$denominations}', '{$_POST['oadd']}', '{$quality}', '{$warr}', '{$prices}', '{$atotal}', '{$_POST['onphone']}', '{$_POST['oname']}', '0', now(), '0')";
                        mysqli_query($CONNECT, $query1);
                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                    } else {
                        echo 'Вы не выбрали ни одной позиции.';
                    }
                    unset($_SESSION['ch']);
```

Comment: И с чем возникли трудности?

Comment: Спасибо за коррекцию вопроса. Трудности с записью в базу данных, не знаю как реализовать это...

Comment: Как записывать данные в базу данных знаю, но как реализовать запись через значения другой таблицы «грубо говоря» не знаю. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неплохо было бы еще и знать типы столбцов таблиц, а не только их названия, ну да ладно.
Из комментария у Вас похоже проблема с незнанием вложенных запросов (хотя на самом деле эту задачу можно решить разными способами, но вот к примеру один из них)

```
$denominations = implode(',', $_POST['ch']);
$quality = $warr = implode(',', $_POST['osel']);

if ($_POST['osel'] == 0) {
    $priceids = implode(',', $_POST['osel']);
    $query = "SELECT `priceor` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN ({$priceids})";

} else {
    $query = "SELECT `pricecopy` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN ({$priceids})"
}

$prices_query = MYSQL_QUERY_EXEC($query);

$prices = implode(',', $prices_query);

$atotal = 0;
foreach($prices_query as $p) {
    $atotal += $p;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `orders` (`denominations`, `additional`, `quality`, `warr`, `prices`, `atotal`, `ophumber`, `oname`, `status`, `date`, `uid`) 
VALUES('{$denominations}', '{$_POST['oadd']}', '{$quality}', '{$warr}', '{$prices}', '{$atotal}', '{$_POST['onphone']}', '{$_POST['oname']}', '0', now(), '0')"

MYSQL_QUERY_EXEC($query);
```

Ну и естественно не забываем ВСЕ ВХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ перепроверять и использовать [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

PS. Код написан на "коленке" и на скорую руку, поэтому возможно нужны будут правки, но смысл думаю понятен.

PS2. **MYSQL_QUERY_EXEC** - это моя абстрактная (придуманная) функция

Comment: Разбудите меня через сто лет, спросите, что пхпшники? Отвечу - используют real_escape_string.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393450/177221

Comment: яж написал, что код писан на коленке и все данные **нужно** валидировать

Comment: спасибо, сегодня буду пробовать

Comment: MYSQL_QUERY_EXEC - что делать будет эта функция?

Comment: она идет как mysqli_query?

Comment: и $query, там где $priceids не надо циклить или в заносить в массив?

Comment: MYSQL_QUERY_EXEC - должна выводить что-то типа http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: и "циклить" ничего не нужно, уже весь массив объединится через implode(), (почитать про эту функцию можно тут http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас буду разбираться

Comment: а как еще можно вывести на экран `id` строки, которую только что записали?

Comment: и не записывает в колонки `prices` и `atotal` (В самом вопросе привел уже исправленный код).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php - это после строки "mysqli_query($CONNECT, $query1);"

Comment: а что значит не записывает? var_dump($prices, $atotal) что показывает перед insert-ом? Может там и нет ничего?

Comment: По поводу ID спасибо. Не записывает данные, сейчас буду делать как вы отписали.

Comment: и раз уж на то пошло, то вы неправильно извлекаете все строки из SELECT-ов. Перечитайте еще раз мануал по работе данной функции и обратите внимание на примеры процедурного стиля, особенно на вот эти строки.

    /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
    }

Comment: выше исправил, правильно?