# Массив значений в POST запрос

Tags: javascript, php

В целом нужно передавать в БД сразу несколько строк данных. На уровне PHP, я вроде понял что нужно делать. Но не могу понять как создать образно вот такой POST запрос, чтобы его обработать и передать в БД

```
$_POST = [
    'visited' => [
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    'user_id' => [
        20,
        30,
        30
    ],
    'dates' => [
        '12-12-2015',
        '12-12-2016',
        '12-12-2017',
    ]
];
```

Видимо нужно как-то в While помещать input'ы, но не знаю как.
У меня вопрос именно по вводу данных.

```
<form action="dob_tool.php" method="post" id="submit1">                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th> Артикул</th><th> Наименование</th><th> Группа товара</th><th> Ед. измерения</th></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="text" name="code" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="groups" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Группа товара"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="unit" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th><input type="text" name="code" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Артикул"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Наименование"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="groups" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Группа товара"></th>
                                <th><input type="text" name="unit" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ед. измерения"></th></tr>
                        </table>
</form>
```

Можно на кнопку в конце поставить clik, чтобы данные отправлялись в AJAX, но на сделать чтобы они отправлялись структурировано, построчно?

Comment: Как отправляется запрос с клиента? У вас три идентичных формы? Или вы аяксом отправляете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764649/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-mysql

Comment: Вот в этом и вопрос, как лучше? И покажите образ как это должно выглядеть. Думаю Ajax лучше

Comment: $arr = [
    'visited' => [
        1,
        1,
        1
    ],
    'user_id' => [
        20,
        30,
        30
    ],
    'dates' => [
        '12-12-2015',
        '12-12-2016',
        '12-12-2017',
    ]
];

echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  # code...

echo '<input type="hidden" name="data14[]" value='.$value.'>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" class="orange12" value="Отправить">';
echo '</form>';
echo '<br>';

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="dob_tool.php" method="post" id="submit1">
   <p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
   <p>Ваш возраст: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>  



$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       let param = $( this ).serialize(); // получаем параметры формы
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'you_url_to_php_file',
            data: JSON.stringify(param), // зашифровываем в json
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg) {
                     console.log(msg)
             }
         });
    });
```

Comment: Это я тоже понимаю как сделать. Я не пойму, как оформить ввод данных. <form action="dob_tool.php" method="post" id="submit1">
</form>

Answer (score 0):

1. я бы развернул, чтоб было по строкам: `[{"visited":1,"user_id":20,date:"2015-12-12"},{"visited":1,...]`
2. использовал `JSON.stringify`
3. на сервере парсил JSON; делал prepared statement; и по циклу биндил и запускал.