# sql-запрос update оставляет поле пустым

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, update

Всем доброго времени суток!
Такой вопрос: есть форма следующего вида

```
<h3>Изменение статуса</h3>
<form action="edit_user.php" method="post">
        Введите логин: <input type="text" value="" name="login">
    <p>Введите новый логин: <input type="text" value="" name="new_login">
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Изменить">

</form>
```

где можем поменять логин пользователя из бд `log_in` с атрибутами `id`, `login`. И обработка

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $new_log = $POST['new_login'];
    $my_sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `log_in` SET `login`='".$new_log."' WHERE `log_in`.`login`='".$login."'");
}
```

но при update поле остается пустым, а не обновляется, т.е. опустошается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, стоит написать $new_login вместо $new_log.

Comment: @msi когда имена переменных начинают влиять на функциональность, пора выключать компьютер

Comment: Интересно, по каким учебникам люди учатся? Какие вредители эти учебники распространяют? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/393450/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/637185/186083

Comment: @Visman мировая закулиса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**_**

```
$new_log = $_POST['new_login'];
```