# Phpmyadmin и php. Ошибка в запросе к БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, парсер, phpmyadmin

Делаю парсинг сайта.
Создал скрипт, задачи которого: спарсить названия, описания и изображения с сайта о рыбалке, а также создать записи в базе данных.
Частично скрипт работает: изображения скачиваются, база данных заполняется. Но, по-видимому есть какая-то ошибка в коде, из-за которой скрипт останавливает свою работу и до конца не скачивает контент.
В браузере выводится следующее:
*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'северной широты рыба судак встречается ред�' at line 1*

В скрипте я делаю такой запрос к базе данных:

```
if(empty($data)){
        $query="INSERT INTO content2 SET name='".$name."', text='".$text."',img = 'image/".$filename.".jpg', data=NOW() ";
        mysqli_query($link,$query)or die(mysqli_error($link));
    }
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, где и в чём ошибка?

Comment: Когда в переменной `$name`, например, есть кавычка `'` то твой текст запроса превращается в тыкву)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя так формировать запрос. Переменные, передаваемые в запрос - нужно предварительно "экранировать". Текстовые значения - 100%. Вот пример функции, которая поможет: [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Вообще, по-хорошему, для предотвращения SQL-инжекта - лучше использовать

`$pdo->prepare()`

по типу:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
  'SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE YEAR(created) = ? AND MONTH(created) = ?'
);
if ($stmt->execute([$_GET['year'], $_GET['month']])) {
    $posts = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Тогда и ничего esc-апить не придется в добавок. [Вот тут](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide) по этой теме целая статья.

Comment: Сделал немного по-другому. Переменную $text поместил в функцию addslashes. Запрос принял такой вид: if(empty($data)){
        $query="INSERT INTO content2 SET name='".$name."', text='".addslashes($text)."',img = 'image/".$filename.".jpg', data=NOW()";
        mysqli_query($link,$query)or die(mysqli_error($link));
    } Правильно ли я сделал или лучше использовать mysqli_real_escape_string?

Comment: Я отредактировал свой ответ - там и ссылка есть полезная :)

Comment: Спасибо, я учту!