# Как избежать ошибок и sql инъекции в запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Вот обработка данных как происходит

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';

if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

// преобразуем специальные символы в текст

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$rating = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rating']);

// заносим данные из формы в переменные и проверяем на ошибки

$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$text = strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']));
$message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message']));
$rating = strip_tags(trim($_POST['rating']));
$date = $_POST['date'];

// заносим дату и время отзыва
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');

// проверка введенных данных

if($name != '' AND $text != '' AND $message != '')

// отправка данных в бд

mysqli_query($link, " INSERT INTO Otzivy2 (name, text, message, date, rating) VALUES ('$name', '$text', '$message', '$date', '$rating')");
$to      = 'почта';
$subject = 'review';
$message = "Текст отзыва: " . $_POST['message'] . "\nОт: " . $_POST['text'] . " " . $_POST['email'] . "\nВремя: " . date("d.m.Y - H:i");
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'почта',
    'Reply-To' => 'почта',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}




// закрываем сеанс


include_once 'clear.php';
include_once 'form.php';

?>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-sql-injection)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для того чтобы навсегда избежать любых проблем с передаваемыми в запрос данными, будь то ошибки или взлом сайта, любые данные надо всегда передавать в базу данных **отдельно от запроса**. Это делается с помощью подготовленных, или, как их ещё называют, параметризованных запросов.

В mysqli, чтобы выполнить параметризованный запрос, необходимо выполнить 4 действия:

- Заменить все переменные в запросе на специальные маркеры, которые называются плейсхолдеры или параметры, а по сути - просто знаки вопроса
- Подготовить запрос к исполнению с помощью функции prepare(). Эта функция принимает строку запроса и возвращает экземпляр специального класса mysqli_stmt, с которым в дальнейшем и производятся все манипуляции
- Привязать переменные к запросу с помощью bind_param(). Это очень интересная функция. Она принимает в качестве параметров все переменные, которые должны попасть в запрос, в том же самом порядке, в котором стоят плейсхолдеры в запросе. Но кроме того, сначала в этой функции [должны быть указаны типы для всех переменных](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), в виде строки, где тип переменной обозначается одной буквой. То есть букв в этой строке должно быть ровно столько, сколько дальше будет переменных. К счастью, можно особо не париться с типами и для всех переменных указывать тип "s".
- Выполнить запрос с помощью с помощью execute(). Эта функция выполняется без параметров

На словах это звучит длинно, но на практике получается не так сложно. Но сначала надо правильно написать **код подключения к БД**, чтобы не было проблем с русскими буквами и чтобы база сообщала обо всех ошибках:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '1', '1', 'vk2');
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Этот код надо написать один раз, желательно в отдельном файле, и потом подключать этот файл в другие скрипты где нужна работа с БД. Помимо прочих полезных вещей, этот код сообщает mysqli, что надо генерировать ошибку РНР каждый раз, когда возникла ошибка запроса, чтобы ее можно было отследить и исправить. (Примечание: чтобы видеть сами ошибки, надо [соответствующим образом настроить РНР](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423439/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole/423446#423446))

И после этого можно приступать собственно к выполнению запроса

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Otzivy2 (name, text, message, date, rating) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $text, $message, $date, $rating);
$stmt->execute();
```

**То же самое** касается и запросов SELECT. Только для получения результата запроса надо выполнить еще одну команду - get_result().

Например

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Otzivy2 LIMIT ?,?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $start, $num);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // получаем result
```

а дальше как обычно fetch или while

Comment: А "sssss" это какие данные?

Comment: Понял это это присвоение буквы и столько ее сколько параметров

Comment: с Селектом крашится страница

Comment: Надо проверить запрос. Самому его написать, а не тупо копировать. Плюс включить отображение ошибок как написано здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423446/179379 прочитать ошибку и исправить