# При переборе массива в цикле результат применения функции к элементам массива не сохраняется

Tags: php, массивы

Доброй ночи.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Никак не могу понять как правильно очищается массив с помощью htmlentities сущностей.

Пример кода:

```
$x = ['hello'=> '<script>', 
     'world'=>'<?php echo Hello?>'];


foreach ($x as $v) {

    $clean=htmlentities($v);

}

print_r($clean);
```

В данном случае в массиве 2 значения и они очищаются, но как только я добавляю 3-й ключ и 3-е значение, на выходе получается только последнее значение, 2 остальных пропадают.

Вот пример с 3-мя ключами, который выводит только последнее значение, а первые два - нет.

```
$x = ['hello'=> '<script>', 
      'world'=>'<?php echo Hello?>', 
      'ayco'=>'<style>'];

foreach ($x as $v) {

    $clean=htmlentities($v);

}

print_r($clean);
```

В чем была не права?

Comment: массивы не "очищают" с помощью htmlentities. вообще никогда. но в общем случае, для того чтобы обработка элемента не пропала, его надо записать обратно в массив

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо за совет. А как тогда очищать данные правильно, если их около 20 штук в массиве?? Неужели каждую отдельно взятую переменную прописывать??

Comment: Никак не очищать. Во-первых Htmlentities ничего не "очищает". Во-вторых, применять эту функцию надо при выводе. А там и проблемы такой не будет

Comment: @Ипатьев переформулирую вопрос. Как обрабатывать данные чтобы при получении их от пользователей в форме они представли в безопасном виде и записались в базу данных, чтобы не было <script> <?php и прочих попыток как-то встроить Sql инъекции.

Comment: Для начала надо подумать, какое вообще отношение может иметь функция с названием HTMLentities к SQL инъекциям. Вот просто на минутку задуматься. А про скрипты я писал выше - это делается при выводе.

Comment: @Ипатьев  PHP создан чтобы управлять значениями переменных и массивов, все что вводит пользователь в основном в нашем случае - это текс и цифры, иные символы, которые нужно обработать. Просто напишите как эти данные обезопасить, с помощью каких функций, дальше я сама найду.

Comment: Как защититься от SQL инъекции я только что отвечал, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: А про скрипты, я уже два раза сказал, htmlspecialchars **при выводе**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не изменяете исходный массив, а создаёте новую переменную, которая перезаписывается при каждой итерации `foreach`, а выводится один раз после всех итераций, то есть выводится последнее её значение.

Чтобы изменить исходный массив, нужно на него ссылаться при помощи «&» ([Присваивание по ссылке](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.assignment.php)):

```
$array = [
    'hello' => '<script>', 
    'world' => '<?php echo Hello?>', 
    'ayco' => '<style>'
];

foreach ($array as &$linked_value) {

    $linked_value = htmlentities($linked_value);

}

print_r($array);
```

Или использовать ключи:

```
$array = [
    'hello' => '<script>', 
    'world' => '<?php echo Hello?>', 
    'ayco' => '<style>'
];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    $array[$key] = htmlentities($value);

}

print_r($array);
```

Если вы пытаетесь предотвратить инъекции, вам не поможет `htmlentities` — почитайте ответы на вопрос «[Грамотная защита от SQL-Injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-sql-injection)»

Comment: вот прямо двойственные чувства. безукоризненно грамотный ответ - но во ответ на совершенно бессмысленный вопрос, и как результат - показывающий как выполнить бессмысленную и вредную работу.