# Как добавить в БД значение null, если поле не было заполнено?

Tags: php, mysql

Я только знакомлюсь с пхп, и пытаюсь организовать добавление полей в БД, через инпуты. Обработчик у меня выглядит следую

```
require_once "connect.php";
$loc1 = $_POST["loc1"];
$loc2 = $_POST["loc2"];
$loc3 = $_POST["loc3"];
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `locbase` (`id`, `loc1`, `loc2`, `loc3`) VALUES (NULL, '$loc1', '$loc2', '$loc3')");
header('Location: admin.php');
```

Проблема заключается в том, что в БД добавляются значения, только если все 3 поля заполнены. А я бы хотел добавлять, даже если одно заполнено, а остальные пустые.

Спасибо.

Comment: *пытаюсь организовать добавление полей в БД, через инпуты.* Это называется "вставить запись". Добавление полей - совсем иная операция. *в БД добавляются значения, только если все 3 поля заполнены.* А если не все - что наблюдается? подробно...

Comment: Прошу прощения, еще плохо знаком с терминологией. Если не все поля добавляются, то ничего не происходит - возвращает на страницу header('Location: admin.php'); а если убрать то на пустой странице обработчика

Comment: *Если не все поля добавляются, то ничего не происходит* Не верю. По всему - должно приходить от MySQL сообщение об ошибке, просто Вы его не выводите (и вообще не проверяете на ошибку). А надо... в общем, делайте, а потом приходите и показывайте точный и полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Говорю же "Я только знакомлюсь с пхп". Я не знаю как вывести ошибку mysql и это не гуглится быстро..

Comment: Я немного разобрался. Проблема в том, что тип данных в БД указан как "datetime". Если его поменять на varchar или integer то всё добавляется, однако хотелось бы оставить, этот тип данных. Скорее нужно разрешить атрибут NULL в БД.

Comment: помимо разрешения нулл в БД надо еще и само поле превратить из пустой строки в нулл

Comment: а для этого надо переделать запрос на подготовленные выражения

Comment: в sql запросе можно пропускать некоторые поля (те что в скобках), также при создании таблицы можно указать, что поле по-умолчанию может принимать значение null.

Answer (score 0):

Записать значение null в бд несложно. Нужно сделать всего две вещи.

1. Использовать подготовленные выражения. Поскольку их все равно надо **всегда** использовать при вставке, то этот пункт скорее риторический
2. Собственно превратить пустую строку, которая приходит из формы когда поле не заполнено, в значение null

Итоговый код будет базироваться [вот на этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218197/179379)

```
# соединяемся с БД. лучше делать это в отдельном файле
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '1', '1', 'vk2');
$db->set_charset('utf8mb4');

# превращаем пустые строки в null
$loc1 = $_POST["loc1"] ?: null;
$loc2 = $_POST["loc2"] ?: null;
$loc3 = $_POST["loc3"] ?: null;

# выполняем подготовленный запррос. все пояснения по ссылке выше
$sql = "INSERT INTO `locbase` (`loc1`, `loc2`, `loc3`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $loc1, $loc2, $loc3);
$stmt->execute();
```