# Как обновить запись через форму?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть страница с заметками и комментариями к ним, там есть ссылка изменить заметку, при нажатии ссылки открывается другая страница (код этой страницы внизу). На странице 2 текстового поля и кнопка "изменить". В текстовых полях должны быть тема заметки и сама заметка, которую мы собираемся изменить. По заданию мы должны поменять тему заметки и заметку, и при нажатии кнопки изменить заметка должна обновиться. Программа не выводит никакую ошибку, но и изменение заметки тоже не получается. В чем ошибка?

```
<?php
$note_id = $_GET['note'];
require_once ("MySiteDB.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = '{$note_id}'";
$result = mysqli_query ($link, $query);
$edit_note = mysqli_fetch_array ($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<p>Заголовок заметки: <input type="text" name="title" 
value = "<?php echo $edit_note['title'];?>" /></p>
<p>Текст заметки: <textarea name="article">
<?php echo $edit_note['article'];?></textarea></p> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Изменить" />
</form>
<a href = "default.php"> На главную </a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$title = $_POST['title'];
$article = $_POST['article'];
$update_query = "UPDATE notes SET title = '$title', article = '$article'
WHERE id = $note_id";
$update_result = mysqli_query ($link, $update_query);
?>
```

Comment: Почему же не получается? Этот код работает и меняет содержимое заметок. На пустоту. Поскольку запрос на обновление вызывается каждый раз при вызове скрипта. А ошибки он не выводит потому что вывод ошибок выключен. Если бы был включён, то писал бы Notice: Undefined index: title. А в целом это очень плохой код - классический мусорный РНР, который преподают в колледжах под видом настоящего.

Comment: я новичок в PHP, я знаю что код плохой, нет нужды об этом писать. Я надеялась что кто нибудь поможет мне найти ошибку или переделать код чтобы он работал.

Comment: Код плохой не потому что новичок, а потому что преподают его так. А ошибку найти просто - для начала надо включить отображение ошибок. как это сделать можно посмотреть например [здесь](http://phpfaq.ru/debug)

Answer (score 0):

- Чтобы форма не перезаписывалась каждый раз, надо проверять, что она была отправлена.
- Чтобы при редактировании не возникало ошибок и угроз безопасности, надо использовать подготовленные выражения, как описано в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218197/179379)
- после обработки POST запроса **всегда** должен быть редирект
- по этой, а так же по многим другим причинам, весь РНР код должен быть написан в начале скрипта
- выводимые в HTML значения должны соответствующим образом форматироваться, чтобы избежать ошибок и угроз безопасности

Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
<?php
require_once ("MySiteDB.php");
$note_id = $_GET['note'];
if ($_POST) {
    $sql = "UPDATE notes SET title = ?, article = ? WHERE id = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST['title'], $_POST['article'], $note_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $note_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$note = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
  <form method="POST">
    <p>Заголовок заметки: 
      <input type="text" name="title" value ="<?= htmlspecialchars($note['title'])?>" />
    </p>
    <p>Текст заметки: 
      <textarea name="article"><?= htmlspecialchars($note['article'])?></textarea>
    </p> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Изменить" />
  </form>
  <a href = "default.php"> На главную </a>
</body>
</html>
```