# Заполнил столбец таблицы данными массива, но ничего не выводится

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, база-данных, denwer

Есть такой вот массив:

```
$books=array('Detective Comics № 27', 'Action Comics #1', 'All Star Comics #8', 'Showcase №4', 'All-American Comics #16', 'More Fun Comics # 73');
```

Вот такой цикл для заполнения столбца данными массива я использовал:

```
$i=0;
do {$episode=$books[$i];
    $i++;
    $conn->query("UPDATE `heroes` SET `the_first_appear_work`= '$episode' WHERE `id` = $i"); // для этого на единицу переменная и увеличивается, ведь нулевого id в таблице нет
}
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc());
```

Цикл сработал - таблица базы данных заполнилась!

Выборка для вывода у меня происходит вот так:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `heroes`");
```

Выводятся данные из таблицы базы данных на страницу у меня вот так:

```
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <p> <b>ID: </b> <?php echo $row['id']?> 
    Name: <?php echo $row['name']?>
    <?php if (!(empty($row['the_real_name']))) {echo "The real name: "; echo $row['the_real_name'];}?><br>
    The artwork where they first appear: <?php echo $row['the_first_appear_work']?>
    Year of the first appear:  <?php echo $row['the_first_appear']?></p>
    <a href=greeting.php?name=<?php echo $row['name'] ?>> Нажмите, чтобы поприветствовать героя </a><hr> // вот с этим другая проблема
<?php }
```

Сделал через параграфы, а не echo, чтобы стилизовывать.
Да, условие взял отсюда. Ведь когда строки кончаются, то возвращается ложь и цикл, работающий на истине, останавливается.

Так вот столбец таблицы-то заполнился, а данные из таблицы - не выводятся вообще никакие и ошибок нет. Комментирую цикл заполнения - выводятся, в том числе с новыми данными массива, всё хорошо без цикла.

Вопрос: как сделать нормальный цикл, с каким нормальным условием, чтоб работал, и данные из базы на страницу выводились?

Следующий вопрос: вот там ссылка с методом Get передаёт данные, обрезав после пробела. Как сделать, чтобы она передавала данные с пробелом целиком?

Comment: по второму вопросу всё просто. во-первых, надо соблюдать правила синтаксиса HTML, когда пишешь атрибуты тегов. А во-вторых, имя никогда не передают, передавать надо всегда только id.

Comment: А по первому ВООБЩЕ ничего непонятно. Какой-то адов цикл с fetch_assoc() от несуществующего $result и без запроса select. какое-то "заполнение таблицы" запросом update, полный АД когда id берутся почему-то с потолка.

Comment: а, до меня дошло. сначала делается запрос селект, потом делается цикл с запросом апдейт, который и проматывает все фетчи. и на следующий цикл ПОЧЕМУ-ТО ВДРУГ fetch_assoc() возвращает ложь. Вот блин удивительно-то.

Comment: @Ипатьев, так мне и нужна была ложь, чтоб цикл остановился.Я решил проблему:  в условие ставить `$i<=($result->num_rows)`. 
А почему fetch_assoc() не работал при выводе данных, он что, одноразовый?

Comment: потому что ответ на этот вопрос написан в **вашем же вопросе**, "Ведь когда строки кончаются, то возвращается ложь **и цикл, работающий на истине, останавливается**". Останавливается, понимаете? Если строк больше нет, то fetch_assoc() возвращает ложь. И цикл не работает. Логично, правда?

Comment: и **ради бога**, во-первых, в исходном массиве указывайте id **конкретной записи**, которую хотите обновить, и перебирайте массив через **foreach**, без этих адовых безграмотных костылей. Чтобы обновить БД, запрос select ВООБЩЕ не нужен

Comment: То есть в массиве ключом сделать номер id, а значением - данные, которые хочу добавить в поле? И в foreach перебирать по ключ-значение?

Comment: да, и в foreach перебирать по ключ-значение

Comment: ну и запросы надо выполнять [правильно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218184/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8-sql-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1218197#1218197), а не как здесь. Потому что потом полезут ошибки

Comment: @Ипатьев "соблюдать правила синтаксиса HTML, когда пишешь атрибуты тегов" - просто ссылку взять в двойные кавычки, прям с куском PHP.
Foreach`ем удалось перебрать и заполнить столбец данными из массива. 
Благодарю за помощь.