Как заставить sphinxsearch 3.6.1 выводить несколько полей?
При поиске данных выводит только id, а надо еще title и content, как это сделать, написано, что выводит по field в index, у меня там написаны эти поля, но не выводит
Файл конфигурации выглядит так:
{
   datadir     = ./sphinxdata
}

source prezumciya_source
{
 type            = mysql
 sql_host        = localhost
 sql_user        = root
 sql_pass        = 
 sql_db          = wp
 sql_port        = 3306

 sql_query       = SELECT ID AS id, post_title AS title, post_content AS content FROM wp_posts WHERE 
 post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
}

index prezumciya_index
{
 source          = prezumciya_source
 field     = title,content
}

searchd
{
 listen          = 9312
 log             = C:/s/log/searchd.log
 query_log       = C:/s/log/query.log
 read_timeout    = 5
 max_children    = 30
 pid_file        = C:/s/log/searchd.pid
 seamless_rotate = 1
 preopen_indexes = 1
 unlink_old      = 1
 binlog_path     = C:/s/data
} 

идексирую так
indexer --config C:/s/etc/sphinx-min.conf.dist prezumciya_index
запуск searchd --config C:/s/etc/sphinx-min.conf.dist
php код для выполнения запроса и вывода результатов
function sphinx_search($query) {
    $conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '', '', '', 9306);
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content FROM prezumciya_index WHERE MATCH('$query') LIMIT 1000";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result && $result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            print_r($row);
        }
    }
}
sphinx_search('реферат');


Значения полнотекстовых полей по умолчанию не хранятся, нужно включать их хранение явно через stored_fields (документация: Sphinx, Manticore)

А ещё у вас тут уязвимый код из-за sql-инъекции https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1218184

спасибо, stored_fields помог, насчет уязвимости, это пока что просто тестирование

@andreymal можете оформить как ответ?
